# XML null/empty Validation

Tags: xml, validation, jaxb

i am new in validating specially with XML and I've been asked to validate the XML before we make a call for adobe server to generate a PDF,  I have the following where we pass the object to get XML and then we call. can any body help me step by step to validate the XML if there is any element is null or empty to stop the pdf generation

```
public class MyJAXBUtil {

    public static String obj2Xml(Class<?> class, Object object) throws ServiceException {
        try {   
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty( Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE );
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(object, writer);
            return writer.getBuffer().toString();
        } catch (JAXBException jaxbException) {
            throw new ServiceException(jaxbException);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an instance of `Schema` on the `Marshaller` to have validation performed during the `marshal` operation.  In your XML schema you can define the rules for missing elements.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html